# How can I reformat the way a data appears inside an ASP MVC Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code:

```
<li>Reviewed: @Model.Modified</li>
```

and a model that looks like this:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
```

However when displayed then the date appears as follows:

```
REVIEWED: 8/1/2012 2:42:34 PM
```

Is there a simple way that I could change the way the date
displays so it appears as just 8/1/2012 2PM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ToString(format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) in your view as well, to format the date the way you want.

So in your case, something like:

```
@Model.Modified.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy htt")
```

Comment: I would prefer this since, the date format is more of a UI/View concern rather than that of the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834932%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Modified)
```

This helper works with data annotations and display templates.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy htt}")]
   public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
```

This website provides easy to understand information on setting date/time formats

[Date Formatting C#](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/23/Date-Formatting-in-CSharp)